# Regular expression return only certain values PHP

Tags: php

I cant remember what to use to return only a specific part of a string.
I have a string like this:-

```
$str = "return(me or not?)";
```

I want to get the word which is after *(*.  In this example `me` will be my result. How can I do this?

I dont think substr is what I am looking for. as substr returns value based on the index you provided. which in this case i dont know the index, it can vary. All I know is that I want to return whatever is after "(" and before the space " ". The index positions will always be different there for i cant use substr(..).

Comment: Luke, you've already hit on the right keyword; have you tried anything?  http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: https://regex101.com is a cool site to test regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression should do the trick. Since you didn't provide general rules but only an example it might need further changes though.

```
preg_match('/\((\S+)/', $input, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` contains "me" then.

Comment: TY this is what I was looking for. I must have not read right on php.net I was thinking that peg_match only returns true or false.

Comment: Yes, preg_match only returns the number of matches. But the third parameter (if provided) contains the actual matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Your input string
$string = "return(me or not?)";

// Pattern explanation:
// \( -- Match opening parentheses
// ([^\s]+) -- Capture at least one character that is not whitespace.
if (preg_match('/\(([^\s]+)/', $string, $matches) === 1)
    // preg_match() returns 1 on success.
    echo "Substring: {$matches[1]}";
else
    // No match found, or bad regular expression.
    echo 'No match found';
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of capture group will be your result using this regex and preg_match().

```
$regex = '/\((\w+)/';
```

Check preg_match() for the working reference.